# 406 Not Acceptable error

Tags: apache, http-status-code-406

Please take a look at this page:

http://www.carteadenisip.ro/partener/id-753.html - the image is not showing

The image url is http://www.carteadenisip.ro/img/part/27/f_26648.jpeg

If you access the image directly, with no referer, the image shows.

If i debug the page i get this:
f_26648.jpeg /img/part/27 GET 406 Not Acceptable

Comment: Confirmed with `wget --spider http://www.carteadenisip.ro/img/part/27/f_26648.jpeg` (works) and `wget --spider http://www.carteadenisip.ro/img/part/27/f_26648.jpeg --referer=http://www.carteadenisip.ro/partener/id-753.html` (406) that it is definitely having the referrer set which makes the request Not Acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that a apache server protection software was denying all requests with /id-*.html. No idea why the hosting implemented that.

(addition: the hosting did not want to disabled that so i had to change the links to make it work)